# Unwanted row while querying tables

Tags: mysql

I am querying two tables in the same database, I want to have all lines in both database where there is a match but the query should take only row with max date for each file number from file movement table.

[File Details Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drO0o.png)

[File Movement Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Aed.png)

Here is my current Query

[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/634KK.png)

The result should not contain the 1st row for file 123 as the 2nd row has the larger issue date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEA0b.png)

Comment: post your code  ..as text  not only  the image  please

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `b.issue_date` at line 1 of your query with `MAX(b.issue_date)`
2. append `GROUP BY b.file_number` after `ON` condition at last line before semicolon.

SQL query engine generally applies `GROUP BY` operation before applying any aggregate function on any of its column specified after `SELECT` clause while retrieving data.

Therefore, the consequence of the two operations are as follows

**result grouped by** `file_number` -> **result containing only the max value of** `issue_date` **column of** `file_movement` **table for each** `file_number`

Comment: Hello That does not solve the problem, the group by cannot be placed on the 5th line, it gives an error

Comment: My bad. the statement should be added to last line before semicolon. Edited my answer [B.Rutnah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014385/b-rutnah)